# Translate curl command with -X option to python requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to translate the following curl command to python, but it's always giving me back `<Response 400>` status codes. This is what I've tried:

```
curl -H "public-api-token: myAPIkey" -X PUT -d "urlToShorten=google.com" https://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url
```

which to my understanding should be equivalent to:

```
result = requests.put("https://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url",
         data='urlToShorten=google.com',
         headers={
             "public-api-token": "myAPIkey",
         }
)
```

I tried the curl command itself and it works flawlessly. What I suspect to be the problem is the awkward `-X PUT` option although `-d` suggests a POST. More info about this option can be found here: (11.2) http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html

Output of curl:

```
{"status":"ok","shortenedUrl":"http:\/\/sh.st\/caIXv"}
```

Output of python when doing `print result`:

```
<Response [400]>
```

Comment: It returns a 400 response code, which I mention in the second line of my question.

Comment: Let me just clarify it a little better in my original post, one sec...

Comment: As an aside, try inspecting the content of the response (in this case `result.content`). That might give you more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a dictionary for `data`:

```
data = {'urlToShorten': 'google.com'},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib2
request =  urllib2.urlopen(
            urllib2.Request(
            url=url,
            data={"urlToShorten": "google.com"},
            headers={"public-api-token" : "myAPIkey"})
        )
```